# prove about tree graph of including forest

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Show that a forest F has n vertices and n − k edges if and only if it consists of k trees.

I am no idea to start this proof, Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Note that a graph $G$ is a tree iff it has $n-1$ edges.

$\impliedby$ Suppose $G$ consists of $k$ trees and let $n_{1},...,n_{k}$ denote the number of vertices of each tree. Then the number of edges in $G$ is $$\sum_{i=1}^{k}{(n_{i}-1)}=\sum_{i=1}^{k}{n_{i}}-k=n-k$$

$\implies$We prove this by induction on $k$. For the base case, if $G$ has $n-1$ edges then it is a tree. Now if $G$ has $n-k$ edges with $k>1$ then $G$ is disconnected. In particular, it has two connected components, say $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$ with no edges between them. Let $v_{1}\in G_{1}$ and $v_{2}\in G_{2}$, and consider the graph $G'$ obtained by adding the edge $(v_{1},v_{2})$ to $G$. It is a forest and has $n-(k-1)$ edges, so by induction $G'$ has $k-1$ trees. Now deleting the edge $(v_{1},v_{2})$ adds exactly one more tree because there were no more edges between $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$. Thus $G$ has $k$ trees.